# Send Raw arp reply packet in windows

Tags: c, windows, sockets, arp

I am currently learning how to use the windows raw sockets.

I created a raw arp reply frame(includes all headers (ethernet+arp headers)), and when I send it using sendto function,
It fails and return SOCKET_ERROR with error code 10047.

The parameters I used to create the socket are as follows:

```
socket s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_RAW);
```

and also I changed the socket options as follows:

```
int on=1;
setsockopt(s,IPPROTO_IP, 2,(char*)&on,sizeof(on));
```

(By the way, '2' is equal to IP_HDRINCL, for some reason, visual studio didn't recognize it..)

I try to send the packet as follows:

```
socketaddr sa = { 0 };
int SentBytesCount = sendto(s, (char*)&arp_raw_msg,sizeof(Arp_Frame),0,&sa,sizeof(sa));
```

Where Arp_Frame is a struct that includes ethernet header+arp header+18 Bytes for padding.

After this call I get that SentBytesCount is equal to SOCKET_ERROR(-1), and no packet is sent.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Winsock error 10047 is `WSAEAFNOSUPPORT`:

> Address family not supported by protocol family.
>
> An address incompatible with the requested protocol was used. All sockets are created with an associated address family (that is, AF_INET for Internet Protocols) and a generic protocol type (that is, SOCK_STREAM). This error is returned if an incorrect protocol is explicitly requested in the `socket` call, or **if an address of the wrong family is used for a socket, for example, in `sendto`**.

You created an `AF_INET` (IPv4) socket, but you are not passing `sendto()` a valid `sockaddr_in` containing an IPv4 address and port, hence the error. You are passing it an empty `socketaddr` (what is that?) instead.

Any `sockaddr_...` struct you use with a socket must match what the socket's address family expects, as set by the `socket()` call (in your case, `AF_INET`, which uses `sockaddr_in` addresses).

```c
sockaddr_in sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("destination IP address");
sa.sin_port = htons(Destination port number);

int SentBytesCount = sendto(s, (char*)&arp_raw_msg, sizeof(Arp_Frame), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa));
```

---

As for `IP_HDRINCL`, it is defined in `ws2tcpip.h`.

Comment: Thanks!!The reason I didn't use it was because it is an arp reply, hence it is layer 2 protocol, hence there os no IP addresses. So, is there no way to send arp reply without an IP address ?

Comment: Sending ARP packets on other platforms requires `AF_PACKET` and `sockaddr_ll` to get to the Ethernet layer. WinSock does not support those. I don't think you can send raw Ethernet packets with WinSock at all, it seems WinSock's implementation of `SOCK_RAW` can't go below the IP layer. RAW sockets on WinSock's are simply more limited than on other platforms. If switching OSes is not an option then you will have to use a 3rd party packet library, [such as WinPCap](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcap__tut8.html).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to switch OSes, thank you very much! I hope winpcap is similar to winsock so my work is not wasted